# chartValueSelected never gets called

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I utilize https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts in my project.

Here is my code, this is how I declare my ViewController class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ChartViewDelegate
```

declaration of chartView

```
@IBOutlet weak var chartView: LineChartView!
```

inside `viewDidLoad()`

```
self.chartView.delegate = self
```

and this is how I implement delegate method

```
func chartValueSelected(chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, highlight: Highlight)
{
    print(dataSetIndex)
}
```

For some reason, when I swipe across the chart, this method never gets called. Any ideas why this might happen?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Question with insufficient information. Either improve questions or upload the project file somewhere.

Comment: Is ChartView your own class or some third party library? Are you actually calling this delegate method in your ChartView if it's yours?

Comment: chartView is a subclass of LineChartView from ios-charts framework

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I may have expected, the problem was Swift 3 difference in method signature.

**Swift 3**

```
func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) { ... }
```

Comment: thank you! is it just me or is the new IOS charts 3.0 painful? when I set up 2.3 it was easy!

Answer (score 0):

Check with a breakpoint if chatView is initialized in viewDidLoad and check its delegate, then check if the method which call the delegate has ever been called.
You can use po chartView.delegate in the terminal screen
Maybe you are not selecting the chart, this is not a touch up inside button, to call the selected method you have to set selected, if you want this to work like a button maybe there are an action called setHighlighted...

Comment: chartValueSelected method is never called, but self.chartView.delegate = self is called